# How to convert an einsum expression to an equation?

Tags: index-notation

I'm using Python's `einsum` for an operation over two arrays, and I was wondering how to correctly write this operation out in a paper.

Let's say I have two '3d' arrays $A_{i,j,k}$  and $B_{i,k,l}$, and I want a sum-product over index $k$, an outer product over indices $j$ and $l$, and I want to do that for every $i$, i.e. index $i$ is "matched" between $A$ and $B$. I would write that as `einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',A,B)`.

1. Is there an index-based mathematical notation that would let me write all these operations at once? I have looked up actual Einstein summation, but it seems to be defined more narrowly, e.g. for a sum-product but not outer product, and not in a way you could represent "for every $i$...". Specifically for the index $i$, it seems that once an index is repeated, it must be summed over, which I don't want.
2. Is there a set of rules for writing out derivatives with respect to arrays using the same index notation?   E.g. of outer and inner products, repeated operations, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Inner (sum-product) and outer product in index notation works exactly as in `einsum` (it worth noting that the notation and the name `einsum` come from Einstein notation common in tensor algebra). For example, for tensors $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$:

$$
A_{ij}B_{jk} = C_{ik}
$$

Inner product on index $j$ and outer product for everything else.

However, element-wise operation (for matrices, it's called Hadamard product) is not a tensor operation (the result isn't generally a tensor), so there is no widely used notation for that. However, you are not prohibited to invent it yourself:

$$
A_{ijk}\circ_i B_{ikl} = C_{ijl}
$$

(I am once again note that multi-dimensional matrices $A,B,C$ are not tensors from the maths perspective)

Another approach is to separate indices that follow Einstein rule (e.g. lating $i,j,k$) from indices that are just indices (e.g. $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$):
$$
A_{\alpha jk} B_{\alpha kl} = C_{\alpha jl}
$$

In that case $A_{\alpha ij}$ can be tensor for each particular value of $\alpha$